# Adicionar itens numa Expandable List

Tags: java, android

Estou a tentar utilizar uma Expandable List. Nessa Expandable List pretendo colocar como header "as categorias dos meus produtos" e nos items filhos colocar "os meus productos".
No entanto estou a obter o erro "`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1`", quando tento inserir os productos as categorias(headers). Tanto os productos como as categorias eu obtenho-os da minha base de Dados.

```
LinkedHashMap <String, List<String>> expandableListDetail2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> categoria_header = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i=0;
        List<Producto> produtos;
        Database db = new Database(context);
        List<Categorias> categorias;

        categorias = db.getAllCategorias();

        for (i=0; i<categorias.size(); i++){

            expandableListDetail2.put(categorias.get(i).toString(), categoria_header);

            produtos = db.getAllProductos(categorias.get(i).toString());

               for(int j=0;j<produtos.size();j++) {
                   Log.d("Expandable","categoria->"+categorias.get(i).toString());
                   Log.d("Expan","get->"+produtos.get(0).getNomeProducto());
                   categoria_header.add(i,produtos.get(j).getNomeProducto());
               }
}
```

O problema está no `produtos.get(j).getNomeProducto()`.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: `Produtos` é uma lista com 1 item e você está tentando acessar o index **1** (segunda posição).

Comment: @jbueno o meu indice começa em 0 (int j=0).

Comment: Isso eu vi. Eu só falei o que o erro diz, mas realmente não parece fazer muito sentido. Você tem como colocar na pergunta o valor de `produtos.size()`?

Comment: Tem a certeza que o erro é em `produtos.get(j).getNomeProducto()`?

Comment: @jbueno tou a colocar produtos.size() porque acho que é o que faz sentido...

Comment: @ramaral funciona até o Log.d("Expan","get->"+produtos.get(0).getNomeProducto());

Comment: Tire o `i` do *add* em  `categoria_header.add(i,produtos.get(j).getNomeProducto());`

Comment: @ramaral, se eu tiro o i, vou estar a adicionar os meus productos a todas as categorias e não quero isso, eu quero adicionar os productos às categorias que eles correspondem. Não sei se me fiz entender..

Comment: A primeira categoria tem produtos?

Comment: @ramaral, Não..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro acontece quando faz o `add()` na lista *categoria_header*. 
Se a primeira categoria não tem produtos nada é colocado na lista, o `i` é incrementado, passa a `1`, quando tenta fazer o add com `i = 1` dá erro porque `i` não pode ser superior ao *size* da lista.

Se eu entendi o que quer fazer, alter o código assim:

```
LinkedHashMap <String, List<String>> expandableListDetail2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    int i=0;
    List<Producto> produtos;
    Database db = new Database(context);
    List<Categorias> categorias;

    categorias = db.getAllCategorias();

    for (i=0; i<categorias.size(); i++){

        List<String> categoria_header = new ArrayList<String>();

        produtos = db.getAllProductos(categorias.get(i).toString());

       for(int j=0;j<produtos.size();j++) {
           Log.d("Expandable","categoria->"+categorias.get(i).toString());
           Log.d("Expan","get->"+produtos.get(0).getNomeProducto());
           categoria_header.add(produtos.get(j).getNomeProducto());
       }

        expandableListDetail2.put(categorias.get(i).toString(), categoria_header);

    }
}
```

O *HashMap expandableListDetail2* deve receber uma nova lista *categoria_header* por cada categoria. Portanto um novo objecto deverá ser criada dentro do ciclo `for(i=0; i<categorias.size(); i++)`

<sub>Nota: Julgo que deveria alterar o nome *categoria_header* para *categoriaProdutos*</sub>

Comment: Tens razão...eu comecei a ler a descrição e nem vi o codigo...e estive depois a tentar resolver o problema, quando tinha aqui a resposta...Obrigada.